# Is there a way to use assertion functions with complex validations without creating a specific type?

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

I'm receiving data from api and I'd like to add some validations on front-end and get correct types after that validations, but really specific ones.
For example, suppose I'm getting `data` with type `{ keyA?: { property?: string | null | undefined }, keyB?: string | null } | null` and I'd like to be sure `property` is a non empty string, while `keyB` could be null (just to illustrate I don't want to validate every field, it's not a common NonNull~ case).
Is there a way to do it in another function scope (that receives this data) without manually creating a type?

I tried creating a function:

```
function assertData(data: DType): asserts data {
  if(!data) throw new Error('no data')
  if(!data.keyA) throw new Error('keyA undefined');
  if(!data.keyA.property) throw new Error('property undefined');
```

After calling the function, I can use data (not null value), but the `keyA` can be `undefined`. I expected to able to use `data.keyA.property` without problems and already typed as string.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the function to have the following signature:

```
function assertData(data: DType): asserts data is DType & { 
  keyA: { property: string } 
} {
  if(!data) throw new Error('no data')
  if(!data.keyA) throw new Error('keyA undefined');
  if(!data.keyA.property) throw new Error('property undefined')
}
```

We assert that `data` is `DType` but also that `keyA` and `keyA.property` are not undefined.

```
declare const a: DType
assertData(a)
a.keyA.property.charAt(0)
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgFUrAvDA3jA1lMBBAfgC4MYIAnAe2nPGJgGcRyBLAOwHMYAfGNgVwA2gnjH5sAJlABm7KBJgBfADTZcAIXpNWnUQOFK9QwcFPTxAYxAtKbGAEMGDKLTj2Q9gBQT39komQAShJHZ1oGGB8PGBYIgOgYADJSYBg1fBJMCmoXcBJtdi5FGGBi9FSY6U8AQij7QJgQAAsqAHc+KHaAUXIqck8AcjZKSN8BwIqWKtrfADocfAbmto7u3sp+gYW8MUkZOQlxgG5J6br53DxZ7JpwJZbKdrZOmB6+wZvcsF2pWWfDiaKUymKQWQT2ciwCy2JgOfxIaDAUK5NweTz1JEXfDXKi3MCzCxNCF4ECeAAMgSAA)